# Avoid Showing Kendo Tooltip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, tooltip

Here is my tooltip definition:

```
var toolTip = $('.static_grid_wrapper').kendoTooltip({
    filter: "tr[role=row]",
    position: "top",
    content: function (e) {
        var target = e.target; 
        var tooltipMessage = "<table>";

        var a = $(target).data("A");
        if (defined(alpari)) {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>A</td><td>" + a + "</td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>A</td><td>NA</td></tr>";
        }

        var l = $(target).data("L");
        if (defined(l)) {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>L</td><td>" + l + "</td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>L</td><td>NA</td></tr>";
        }

        var s = $(target).data("S");
        if (defined(s)) {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>S</td><td>" + s + "</td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>S</td><td>NA</td></tr>";
        }

        var g = $(target).data("G");
        if (defined(g)) {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>G</td><td>" + g + "</td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            tooltipMessage += "<tr><td>G</td><td>NA</td></tr>";
        }

        tooltipMessage += "</table>";
        return tooltipMessage;
    },
    show: function (e) {

    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

If "a" or "l" or "s" or "g" is undefined, I don't want to show the tooltip. But I couldn't find the method I have to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a designated way to do this at the moment.
Something like this here will probably work from within your content method:

```
// if a or l undefined, don't show the popup ...
if (!a || !l) {
    // replace the popup that was created with a stub so _show doesn't break
    toolTip.popup = {
        open: function() {},
        one: function() {},
        options: {}
    };

    // delete the popup stub
    setTimeout(function () {
        toolTip.popup = null;
    }, 5);
}
```

(see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/yG8be/3/): there's a tooltip on the third column, and it is hidden for every second row)

Comment: Thanks for the sample @Lars. It seems it works grate with version 2013.2.918. But I'm using v2013.3.1119 and it's undefined the expression "toolTip.popup". It seems the object model changed in this version. Do you have any idea about the newer version for the same task?

Comment: [here's the same](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/2d58t/1/) using 2013.3.1119 - it seems to work without changes

Comment: I changed the expression to "var open = e.sender.popup.open;" and it's working for my case too. Tahnks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a robust solution. Here is the scenario: Hold the mouse on the header of the grid. Slightly get the mouse on the first row. As expected, we don't see the tooltip for the first row. Now get the mouse on the second row and again as expected we see the tooltip. Now push the mouse back to the grid header and get on the first row again. Here is the tooltip of first row. :/

Comment: @anilca yeah, that's the problem with hacks like those - I edited in a different way of doing this which seems to work